# socket.emit event for only the current user doesn't fire

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, emit

I'm using **socket.io** and when i want to emit an event from the server to client **only for the connected user** it doesn't work !

I don't have an error or any response :(

Thats my code

```js
// Server.js
var server     = require('http').createServer(),
    io         = require('socket.io')(server),
    logger     = require('winston'),
    port       = 1337;

// Logger config
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(logger.transports.Console, { colorize: true, timestamp: true });
logger.info('SocketIO > listening on port ' + port);

io.on('connection', function (socket){
    logger.info('SocketIO > Connected socket ' + socket.id);

    socket.on('ElephantIO.login', function (user){
        socket.emit('SocketIO.login', user);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        logger.info('SocketIO > Disconnected socket ' + socket.id);
    });
});

server.listen(port);
```

```js
// Client.js
(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

    socket.on('SocketIO.login', function(user) {
        console.log(user);
        alert('SocketIO.login');
    });

})();
```

If i change the `socket.emit('SocketIO.login', user);` with `socket.broadcast.emit('SocketIO.login', user);` to emit this event to the **all other connected user** it works

If i change the `socket.emit('SocketIO.login', user);` with `io.emit('SocketIO.login', user);` to emit this event to the **all connected user** i have the same behavior of the `socket.broadcast.emit('SocketIO.login', user);`

Always the **current user** window don't have a response or an error !

Comment: From a brief glance, there doesn't seem to be an error in the code posted. My thoughts are that there might be an error in the actual code as this code looks like it was truncated a bit. Also, which version of socket.io are you using?

Comment: Where in the code are you sending the initial message?  I just see where both client and server are listening for messages, not where anyone is sending a message.

Comment: I'm using the 1.3.5 version socket.io.

Comment: @jfriend00 To emit the **ElephantIO.login** event i use [elephant.io](https://github.com/wisembly/elephant.io), that's the link of the [example](https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io/blob/master/example/socket.io/1.x/emitter/client.php).

P.S:
It works with **socket.broadcast**

Comment: Can you explain what ElephantIO is doing here and what role it plays in your code?  When I followed your link to ElephantIO, all I found was a PHP webSocket library which doesn't seem relevant here so I was confused.  Clearly you have a socket.io socket object that isn't behaving normally so I'm trying to figure out why that might be.

Comment: @jfriend00 With Normally we emit or receive events from Client.js to Server.js and vice-versa, with ElephantIO we can emit or receive events from a PHP script to Server.js and vice-versa.

Comment: @jfriend00 
Sorry the problem isn't coming from Socket.io. 
I emit an event from the php script using ElephantIO then i have a redirection to another page, that's way i loose the socket(Connected and Disconnected after the redirection). Do you have a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

Try using Socket.io channels to subscribe your user to when they connect, then emit to that channel to just go to that user.

To add the socket to a channel: `socket.join("channel-name");`

To emit to that channel: `io.sockets.in("channel-name").emit("signin",data);`

Comment: if you are going to down vote my answer, please tell me why you are down voting it.

Comment: Using a chatroom is a fine feature, but doesn't appear to have anything to do with the OP's question.  You can send a message to a single user just fine without using a chat room.  Please explain what the OP's problem is and why this would fix it.

Comment: OP said he would like to send a message to a single user. Using a channel allows OP to do this both once and multiple times throughout the lifetime of the socket without needing to retain a reference to the socket variable for the clients connection. OP said the emit to the socket was not working, so i suggested a workaround that allowed him to utilize the same socket connection again in the future.

Comment: So you're supposed to create a new chat room name for each separate socket and somehow remember that separate chat room name uniquely for each separate socket?  This just isn't practical when there are many different sockets connecting in and it just isn't required since you can just use the `socket` variable you already have.  If a `socket.emit()` isn't working, there's something fundamentally wrong in the implementation that should be diagnosed and fixed and that's what an appropriate answer here should address.

Comment: I mean namespacing the channel to the users unique ID can work just as well. My point is that there is nothing wrong with my answer, and there is no reason to down vote a perfectly acceptable answer just because it isn't exactly how you would do it. In fact, you haven't offered a solution of your own yet.

Comment: If others think this is a good answer, they can upvote it.  If the OP thinks this is the best way to solve their problem, they can accept it.  I am entitled to my own opinion and my own votes.  I haven't offered an answer myself because I don't think the fundamental problem is apparent in what the OP has disclosed.  I also really have no idea what this ElephantIO thing is that may be part of why it isn't working as a normal socket would be expected to work.